# Android Studio (Java): Changing Color of a Button directly with java not .xml

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm programming a little quiz game and I would like to unlock categories. These categories are locked (grey) and should be orange after unlocking them in a dialog. My problem is that that the color doesn't change directly but after closing and opening the activity again. I don't like it because users are confused that the color doesn't change directly. I thought this would be the right approach:

```
            button_fun.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FBBC55"));
```

Do you know what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

*Edit (More code, tell me if you even need more):*
Important part from Activity1

```
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public void applyunlock(String kat) {
        preferences = getSharedPreferences(KEY,MODE_PRIVATE);
        preferencesEditor = preferences.edit();

        if(kat == "Geografie"){
            geografie.setChecked(true);
            geografie.setClickable(true);
            button_geografie = findViewById(R.id.button_geografie);
            button_geografie.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FBBC55"));
            unlock_geografie = true;
            preferencesEditor.putBoolean("unlock_geografie", true);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I do this already. The color is completly fine. My problem is that the color doesn't change directle but after changing the activity and coming back. Do you need more code?

Comment: It would be great if you could share

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you have not transparent foregtround?
try to use postInvalidate() on button

Comment: Thanks, postInvalidate() solved the problem!